# Getting "encoded string too long error" while running munit in mule 3

Tags: java, mule, utf, anypoint-studio

I have successfully deployed a mule3 project but getting a compile time error while running munit.

**encoded string too long: 122968 bytes**

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 122968 bytes
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.nextBytes(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:874)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:910)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.StscState.sts(StscState.java:475)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.StscState.addNewContainer(StscState.java:148)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.StscTranslator.addAllDefinitions(StscTranslator.java:131)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.compileImpl(SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.java:333)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.compile(SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.java:240)
at org.mule.common.metadata.util.XmlSchemaUtils.getSchemaTypeSystem(XmlSchemaUtils.java:42)
at org.mule.common.metadata.MuleSchemaProvider.findRootElement(MuleSchemaProvider.java:62)
at org.mule.common.metadata.XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.getRootType(XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.java:159)
at org.mule.common.metadata.XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.createFields(XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.java:88)
at org.mule.common.metadata.DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.<init>(DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.java:128)
at org.mule.common.metadata.DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.<init>(DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.java:53)
at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.RequestBodyGenerator.generateRequestBody(RequestBodyGenerator.java:90)
at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.parseWsdl(WSConsumer.java:437)
at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.initialise(WSConsumer.java:91)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:87)
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:89)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
.....
..........
```

Could anyone help me please...?

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing this?

Comment: Which versions of Mule and MUnit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to bug https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-15137. Try upgrading to Mule 3.9.4 and latest MUnit version for Mule 3.9.